# Can chrome notification be notified at selected time (offline)?

Tags: google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

Basic on [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API#other_use_case_ideas) , I see that Service Worker can

> Reacting to a particular time & date

. But I can't find any related document. So, Is there anyway to push notification offline at particular time & date?

Thank you

Comment: Push notification does not work offline. Not even native mobile application support that.

Answer (score 0):

The ability to trigger a notification at a specific date/time (regardless of network connection) can be with an **experimental feature** called [Notification Triggers](https://web.dev/notification-triggers/), so unfortunately, it's not widely available yet.

To experiment with the Notification Triggers API in Chrome enable the `#enable-experimental-web-platform-features` flag in chrome://flags.

```js
const createScheduledNotification = async (tag, title, timestamp) => {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
  registration.showNotification(title, {
    tag: tag,
    body: 'This notification was scheduled 30 seconds ago',
    showTrigger: new TimestampTrigger(timestamp + 30 * 1000),
  });
};
```

Hopefully this will be available in Chrome and other browsers later this year. The article will be updated with the status of the API.